How do Eastern Orthodox Christians view receiving personal inspiration by the Holy Spirit?
What is the doctrine in the Eastern Orthodox Church related to non-Eastern Orthodox Christians having personal spiritual experiences? Do Eastern Orthodox Christians believe people not of their faith can experience God's spirit in a positive/uplifting way? Or is any spiritual experience of a non-Orthodox immediately suspected of prelest?

If Orthodoxy is the true faith (Which is our standpoint), then what about miracles and experiences that happen in other Churches, and may have even happened to us?
Generally speaking the Orthodox view this more subjective experiences as a private matter. Outside of sharing the story with a fellow brother or in private spiritual counsel/confession... it isn't really spoken much about.
There are three broad possibilities as to what these experiences could be...

A creation of our own minds
The work of God preparing us to receive Orthodoxy
Demonic Deception/Prelest


The first is the most obvious in modern days, humans are easily suggestible, mass hysteria, etc. I don't think we need to go into much detail here.


The second is easily summarized by saying that Holy Spirit, who is “everywhere present and fills all things” may come to someone outside the Church in order to open them up to receive the fullness of truth later. God certainly works through other churches.

Personal Story: A priest once explained this 2nd one to me when I asked "Why do the catholics have so many more miracles than us?" "Because they need it more then we do" So from my personal experience it is actually less surprising that God is working miracles outside the church, to attempt to bring them to us. Jesus ate with tax collectors and prostitutes they needed Him and the priests and righteous should have already known Him, this trend continues today with God working to bring those who need signs. (This doesn't mean that the signs and experiences stop)

Demonic is easily seen in the extremes, for example rolling about on the floor writhing in ecstasy when they are "slain in the spirit". While this could be a power of the imagination (the first category), when one gets into the area of speaking in tongues and prophecy, a demonic element is often present. This means it should be treated with skeptical rigor. For example, speaking in tongues is not "unintelligible babbling"

For a more official point of view on the matter of spiritual experiences in general consider this article written by an Archbishop.
Here is an orthodox recording as text (forgive their choice of font color and background! As well as the fact it is written in two columns forcing you to scroll up and down.) regarding false experiences.
And here is another article on the difference between Orthodox Spirituality and other traditions... not quite the same as what you asked, but still useful.
Peace be with you
